# Which pin triggered MCP23017 interrupt

Tags: arduino-mega, interrupt

This is my first post here, so apologies in advance if I've done something against any forum guidelines!

I have a project where I am monitoring multiple switch states with an Arduino using multiple MCP23017 ICs. I found a fantastic [article by Nick Gammon](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=10945&reply=1#reply1) which pretty much does what I want for the first element of the project at least. There are 2 small errors in his expanderWriteBoth and expanderRead routines - swap "send" for "write", and "receive" for "read" and the code works out of the box.

However - Nick's code will only display which pin has triggered the interrupt when the input pin is grounded. If you remove the ground to return the pin to the previous state, it will not state that this pin has changed state.

Can anybody see why this is the case? I have been through the datasheet for the MCP over and over again with no clues...

Any help appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: i think that there were no 2 small errors in 2011 ... libraries change over time

Comment: He's not storing previous state, so it's hard to figure out which buttons were released.

Comment: The datasheet for the MCP23017 shows that the inturrupt condition can be compared with the previous state - the IC stores the previous state internally. If you set DEFVAL to clear, and INTCON to clear, it should compare with previous state.